# Histogram of a Sample with Overlay of Population Density

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, density-function, histogram

To familiarize myself with histograms and probability density functions, I decided to sample various distributions, plot samples' histograms and their corresponding probability distribution functions.

I started with Beta:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import beta, norm

rng = np.random.default_rng()

# Generate data
a = 2.; b = 6 
s = rng.beta(a,b,10000)

# Plot histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(s, 50, density=True, label=r'Sample counts: $\alpha$=2, $\beta$=6')

# Plot pdf
x = np.linspace(beta.ppf(0.001,a,b), beta.ppf(0.999,a,b), 100)
ax.plot(x, beta.pdf(x, a, b),'-', lw=2, color='red', alpha=0.8, label='Beta proba dist function')

ax.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Beta pdf', fontsize=12, fontweight='bold')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Thankfully the result is as-expected.

The trouble started with the normal distribution (standard or not):

```
mu = -2.
sigma = 2.

# Generate data
data = rng.normal(mu,sigma,(10000,1))

# Plot histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots() 
count, bins, ignored = ax.hist(data, bins=100, color = (0.,0.,1,0.6))

# Plot pdf
x = bins
y = np.exp(- (bins - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2) ) / ( sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) )
# or
x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.001,loc=mu,scale=sigma), norm.ppf(0.999,loc=mu,scale=sigma), 1000)
y = norm.pdf(x,loc=mu,scale=sigma)
ax.plot(x, y, color=(1,0,0,0.8), lw=2, label='normal proba dist. function')

plt.axvline(data.mean(), 
            color='r', linestyle='dotted', linewidth=2, 
            label='Distribution mean' + ' (' + str(round(data.mean(),1)) + ')')
ax.set_facecolor((0.4,0.4,0.1,0.3))
ax.set_ylim(0,400)

plt.legend(fontsize=10, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), ncol=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Obviously I expected to get a red bell-shaped curved located at `x=-2` but, no dice, there is what is probably a trivial vertical scaling problem with the generated normal curve's pdf. I am missing something basic and don't know what it is.

Any pointer appreciated.

Comment: Fundamentally, you are mixing up a count/frequency histogram with a density histogram.  The area under a pdf function is 1 (total probability of all outcomes is 1).  If you want the histogram to line up in scale with the pdf, the total area under the histogram must also be 1.

Comment: @Underminer: yes, exactly. Tx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `ax.hist` will plot the histogram in terms of the bin counts / frequency *not* density.

If you want to plot the density (so the figure will be on the same scale as the probability density function you're plotting), just pass the `density=True` keyword argument to `ax.hist`, i.e. do:

```py
count, bins, ignored = ax.hist(data, bins=100, color = (0.,0.,1,0.6), density=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for editing your Question so it could be re-opened.

When showing simulated data or illustrating an analysis that involves simulation, it is always
a good idea to set the seed of the pseudorandom
number generator so others can replicate your work.

I believe @rxFt20 (+1) has the right idea; you need to
plot your histogram of normal data on a 'density'
scale if you want to overlay a density function on the histogram. That is, the sum of the areas of the bars must be unity. Note the label 'Density' on the vertical axis.

I will illustrate the same procedure in the base of R, where
a density histogram is invoked by the parameter
`prob=T`. (More sophisticated graphics in R would use different code, but my intention is to illustrate the
idea of a density histogram, not the R code.)

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rnorm(10^6, -2, 2)
hist(x, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
curve(dnorm(x, -2, 2), add=T, 
 col="brown", lwd=2)
```

[image]

In R, with an additional line of code, you can also show a kernel density estimate of the population density function, based on the data (and independent of the histogram binning). With 100,000 observations, there is not much difference between the actual population density and
the KDE (dotted green curve).

```
...
lines(density(x), col = "green3", 
 lwd=3, lty = "dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for taking the time and for OP's title edit. Much better title indeed. As an aside, for the use case of a simple normal distribution, I would have expected no less from a KDE in terms of quality of fit on the density plot.  I understand that more complex multimodal distributions may cause KDE to err, but this would be for another question  though.

Comment: @Cbhihe. Not a KDE expert. Seldom have trouble with R's default. Occasionally increase or decrease bandwidth. Have always used gaussian kernel (except for idle experimentation). // One difficulty may be for population densities with support shorter than the real line.